# Typescript type of intersection of all objects in array of unknown length

Tags: typescript, types

I have a type of an array of object in Typescript. Let's say:

```
type Arr = [{ toto: string}, {titi: number}];
```

I don't know the length in advance.
I would like to have the type of the merge of all objects in the array, ie the intersection

```
{
  toto: string,
  titi: number
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried `Arr[number]` but this gave us the union `{toto: string}|{toto:number}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you discovered, you can use `Arr[number]` to get a union of all types in the array. You can then use `UnionToIntersection` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) to convert it to a intersection :

```
type Arr = [{ toto: string}, {titi: number}];
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type All = UnionToIntersection<Arr[number]>
```

Comment: Very nice :)  I was trying to write something recursive. Thanks a lot !